# Why use uppercase on both sides for a case insensitive comparison in sql query in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, case-insensitive

Why use `UPPER` or `LOWER` function **on both sides** of '=' when doing a **case-insensitive** comparison in SQL query in Oracle?

E.g.
`SELECT * FROM emp WHERE LOWER(empName) = LOWER('John');`

**Why is it necessary to write LOWER() with "John"** in the above code?

What problems may occur with this ?

`SELECT * FROM emp WHERE LOWER(empName) = 'john';`

Kindly tell.

Comment: The cost of converting a constant string should be minimal compared to the rest of the cost of the query and you don't have to remember to write all lowercase when you're maintaining this code in 2 years time. Whether that's *the* reason why someone chose to do this, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Probably whoever wrote it spent hours debugging once with a query like `where lower(empname) = 'John'`.  I know I've wasted time on such things.

Comment: not in oracle, this is what you do always to `be sure` that comparison is case-insensitive

Comment: The second query makes no sense. It will unnecessarily apply function on the column, thus suppresing any normal index.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: that's true for the first query as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, in second query the value is already in lower case.

Comment: I would rather say, it is better to send the values either in lowercase or uppercase from the application. Why to have an overhead on the database.

Comment: The expression `LOWER(empName)` is the reason why a regular index on `empName` cannot be used. The constant on the other side of the expression is irrelevant for the index usage. And it's better to to the `lower()` on the same system. How do you know your application/programming language uses the same locale rules to do the lowercase as the Oracle database?

Comment: Can a column be declared to have a case-insensitive collation in Oracle? (That's how I prefer to handle problems like this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in the example you provided. However, consider the case when you use user's input to compare your empName with (i.e.,parameterized query). Do you trust that the user will put in 'john' and not 'John' or 'JOHN' or 'jOhN' or 'something else'? If not, you need to wrap the input with LOWER

Comment: @user4449595: plus it's better to apply the same function to both values. Theoretically you could also do a `lowercase()` in your application before sending the value to the database. But then you can't be sure that your programming language and Oracle are using the same locale specific rules to do the lowercase (think of special characters like `ß` or `ö`)

Answer (score 0):

Most databases contain standard settings on both equality and sort for the session.Various combinations will deal with scenarios of different case, diacritic marks, even languages that have a few differences in character set (ß in German can be compared to SS). For Oracle specifically, for simply case insensitive, you can run
Alter Session SET NLS_COMP='BINARY_CI'`

where BINARY_CI is binary comparison and case insensitive. The reason someone would compare lower case is because they don't fully understand that the underlying algorithms of the database have led to drastically different comparisons in their past, and they don't know why. So basically, it's written for if you don't know what your doing.